# padding adjustment for pages and posts (left and right sides) of WordPress site

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a question concerning the adjustment of the left and right padding for the content area of all of the pages and posts of my WordPress site (ethicen.com).  I would like to increase the padding on the left and right sides of the content area of every page/post of my site so that each paragraph of text is more narrow/less wide and thus easier to read.

Any assistance that you may be able to provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Provide example or try to ask at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nikolay : Sorry for not providing an example.  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add CSS globally, you can do it from... **Dashboard > Appearance > Edit CSS.**

In **Additional CSS** you can do.

```
.content-area{
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Also for the best mobile view, you can add media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {

 .content-area{
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

}
```

You can change padding value and screen max-width as per your taste :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this css on the content-area. To prevent the higher padding shown on smaller screens (like smartphone), it is only added to the standard Bootstrap breakpoint (as used in your website) with a minimal width of 992px.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .content-area {
    padding-left: 45px;   /* or another value */
    padding-right: 45px;  /* or another value */
  }
}
```

The Bootstrap in your website will do the rest.